# Querying custom actions published by other users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, custom-action

It is my understanding that a list of a users published custom action in an app can be queried with the following URL.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/gym:workedout?access_token=<accessToken>
```

In this case the app is "gym" and the custom action is "workedout".

My question is; can a user query for custom actions that we're published by other users, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your app can read a user's friends' activity in any Open Graph app, provided they grant you the appropriate permission.
Replace 'me' in your call above with the user ID of your app's user's friend whose activity you want to query - you'll need the appropriate permission (`friends_actions:[APP_NAMESPACE]`)

Short version,using 'gym' and 'workedout' as an example request the `friends_actions:gym` permission from the user, and then query `/<user id>/gym:workedout`

It has to be done for specific friends, not on the /friends connection, so for a given user, the best way to see 'all activity published by their friends (**and visible to that user** (you'd be surprised how many people don't consider this..)), is to:

- Request `user_actions:APP_NAMESPACE` and `friends_actions:APP_NAMESPACE` permission from the user
- Get a list of that user's friends who use the app. If you're doing this in the same app, you can do so by calling `/me/friends?fields=installed` and looking for the users with `installed: true`
- If you're doing this from a **DIFFERENT** app, you'll need the user to tell you which of their friends use the app if you want to optimise your query, otherwise you'll need to break their entire friends list into batches before doing the next step
- Request a list of the friends' actions in that app by calling `/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION_NAME?ids=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_UIDS` (example: `/gym:workedout?ids=4,5,1234567889,1111111111`)

  - Caveat: you also need to know what the action is called in the API; i'm not sure of a good way to do this if it's for an app other than your own (anyone got an idea?)

Comment: Thank you for your response, that's useful info. Is there any aggregation of all actions taken in the app, (i.e. independent of the viewers relationship to the publisher)?

Comment: No, you'd need to track all the actions on the app's side (if it's your app) to generate a wider overview; in general the API will only give you information about a) the current user, b) their friends, and c) completely public information

Comment: Is see. So custom actions cannot be public object.

Comment: well, they could be, but you can't 'query' for them, you'd already need to know the IDs somehow

Comment: Does it make any difference if the action is published by the app on behalf of the user (i.e. using user id and app_token instead of me)? Can a list of all actions published by the app on behalf of users be queried?

Comment: No I think you need to know the action name (i.e workedout in that example) you can't see 'everything posted by the `gym` app)

Comment: Hey Igy, I really appreciate all you help, thank you. I am however having trouble implementing your code. If I publish an action with a url of the form <userID>/<appNameSpace>:<ActionName>?access_token=<appToken>, the post is successful. If I then make a get call with a URL of the form me/<appNameSpace>:<ActionName>?access_token=<myAccesstoken> I see the published action but if I make a get call with a URL of the form <myUserID>/<appNameSpace>:<ActionName>?access_token=<appAccessToken> there are no errors but I get an empty JSON list? Any ideas on how to publish to the latter list?

Comment: I don't think the App Access token works for that, i think it needs to be a user access token